# Git require credentials on submodules

Tags: git, authentication, git-stash

I have some troubles with Git.

I have repo (RepoA) that used another repo as submodule(RepoB). both of them are hosted on same server.

Git server managing under Stash.

I added same ssh key for both projects (Deployment key).

If I cloning RepoB, all is OK
If I cloning Repo A(without cloning submodules), all is OK too, but when I call `git submodule update` than I getting request for password for user `git`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which url is used in the .gitmodules to reference B in repo A?

Comment: Thank you for question. I forgot write protocol ssh in url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found mistake. Many thanks to @VonC for question that which sent me to the right path.

Path to RepoB was `git@server/path-to-repo` but correct was `ssh://git@server/path-to-repo`. If I understood correctly when I set wrong path git tried to get repo by HTTP protocol, and required credentials

Comment: Interesting to know. Good feedback. +1